# Change the style of chapters (sections) of the .pdf document from rstudio with knitr PACKAGE LATEX "titlesec"

Tags: r, yaml, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I try to style the chapters (sections) of an article document (documentclass: article) using the latex titlesec package, but I don't get any results, I mean that when I configure the document there is no change.

In the YAML header of rmarkdown

```
header-includes:
## Style Chapter - package "TITLESEC"
  - \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  - \usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
```

Outside the YAML header

```
<!-- TITLESEC - Estilo CAPÍTULOS -->
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

In the .tex file the code of the chapter (section):

```
\hypertarget{name-section}{%
\section{Name Section}\label{name-section}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a working template for you.

You can tune it further as you wish.

```
---
title: "test"
header-includes: 
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
documentclass: report 
---

\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\chapter{RMarkdown}

\chapter{Stackoverflow}
```

Comment: Thanks. Excellent answer. I was defining the document class (```documentclass```) as ```article```, the right thing to do is to use ```report```.

Comment: @JoséCarlos yes, or ```book```.